# NSIS conditional statement

Tags: nsis, conditional-statements

I am writing a script code which installs 3 drivers. Every time that a driver is installed I get a return code of '256' or '1' if the installation was successful, or a different return code if the installation failed. I need to check that all installations finished sucessfully, so I use the following code:

`${If} "$2" == "1"   
${OrIf} "$1" == "256"   
${AndIf} "$2" == "256"  
${OrIf} "$2" == "1"
${AndIf} "$3" == "256"  
${OrIf} "$3" == "1"
    MessageBox MB_OK "Installation was successful!"
${Else}
    MessageBox MB_OK "Sorry, an error occurred during installation."
${EndIf}`

Even if a driver installation fails I receive the message "Installation was successful!". Could someone help me  find the mistake in the above code?

Comment: Why don't you check return code one by one instead of all 3?

In this way you can how which one is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example code the first `${If}` is using `$2` when it should probably check `$1`.

I don't think you should use `OrIf` and `AndIf` in the same if block like this, the results are probably undefined.

It is also possible to write your own custom LogicLib operators:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!macro _MyCheckExitcodeSuccess _a _b _t _f
    !if `${_f}` == ``
        !undef _f
        !define _f +2 
    !endif
    IntCmp ${_b} 1 +2
    IntCmp ${_b} 256 `${_t}` `${_f}` `${_f}`
    !if `${_t}` != ``
        Goto `${_t}`
    !endif
!macroend
!define MyCheckExitcodeSuccess `"" MyCheckExitcodeSuccess`

StrCpy $1 1
StrCpy $2 256
${If} ${MyCheckExitcodeSuccess} $1
${AndIf} ${MyCheckExitcodeSuccess} $2
    MessageBox mb_ok "All OK"
${Else}
    MessageBox mb_ok "Something failed"
${EndIf}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are right, first control is on $1, it is a typo on the code I posted. I am new in nsis scripting, is there any tutorial on how writing a custom LogicLib?

Comment: Is it possible to add comments to your macro code explaining what each line does? Thank you.

Comment: A logiclib operator is just a macro that starts with `_`. If you have a macro: `!macro _Example _p1 _p2 _t _f` it can be used like this: `${If} 123 Example 456` and logiclib will then execute `!insertmacro _Example 123 456 jumpLabelIfTrue jumpLabelIfFalse`. This is complicated by the fact that sometimes one of the labels can be empty because that normally just means continue on the next line. If the macro only had to do one IntCmp the whole macro body would just be `IntCmp ${_p1} ${_p2} ${_t} ${_f} ${_f}` or something like that.

Comment: Could you please explain where '${_t}' and '${_f}' are initialized and when they receive values.

Comment: Inside logiclib.nsh. Which one of them is empty depends on if you used If or IfNot and Or/AndIf etc..

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So if I write ${If} ${MyCheckExitcodeSuccess} $1 then logiclib will execute !insertmacro _MyCheckExitcodeSuccess ${MyCheckExitcodeSuccess} $1 _t _f? Could you please explain where ${MyCheckExitcodeSuccess} is defined?

Comment: You see it in my code, it is defined as '"" MyCheckExitcodeSuccess' because the _a parameter is not used so it can be "".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Your macro seems to work as I needed!

Comment: There is literlly not a single line of documentation about those custom LogicLib operators on the internet in 2023 anymore. Thanks for this answer and comments. Helped mi guess all the missing bits and peaces to write my own custom operator :)

Comment: @MichałMaciejGałuszka This is probably not the best example of one. The macro name needs the _ prefix. a and b are the input and t and f are the true/false jump labels.

Answer (score -1):

A slightly slimpler way would be to do something like

```
; 1_256_1_256 is defined if we are good
!define $1_256_$2_256
!define $1_256_1_$2
!define 1_$1_1_$2
!define 1_$1_$2_256


!ifdef 1_256_1_256
   message mb_ok "All good"
!else
   message mb_ok "Failure detected"
!endif
```